# AJAX GET request to a different URL appends original URL with GET query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

After making an AJAX GET request to a different URL, the original URL from which the call was made is also appended with GET query.

With the below code, an AJAX request with data='a' is successfully made to the url

```
localhost:8000/ajax/search?query=a
```

Below is my AJAX request code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/search",
            data: {query: data},
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function (a) {                        
                    console.log(a);
            }
});
```

But, after a JsonResponse is successfully received(I have confirmed), the URL of the original page from which AJAX request was made is appended with GET data. How do I prevent the get request being appended to original URL?

Here is the log data from the Django server:

```
"GET /username/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2947
"GET /ajax/search?query=a HTTP/1.1" 200 96
"GET /username/?query=a HTTP/1.1" 200 2947
```

I want my URL after AJAX response to be /username/

Comment: What is the original URL from where you are making the ajax call?

Comment: Use: `url: "http//:sitename/ajax/search"`

Comment: @SijanBhandari The first line(URL) in the server log is from where I'm making the AJAX call. The second line is the URL to which I'm calling. The third URL is supposed to be the same as the first, but instead the query parameter from the call is being appended here also for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope there is some function while clicking some button in your page. In that case,
      event.preventDefault();

```
 $("#form").submit(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault(); <------
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/search",
        data: {query: data},
        dataType: "json",                
        success: function (a) {                        
                console.log(a);
        }
});
```

});

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question: *"How do I prevent the get request being appended to original URL"*

Comment: The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening. In your case, the default action is submit for search. Because you want to override it and make ajax call.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is not that it is submitted twice, the issue is that the url has the wrong url.

Comment: I solved the issue by making the button of submit type and then calling the preventDefault() function as above

Comment: Glad that it somehow help you out.

Comment: I know this is old, but another possible problem that causes this issue is leaving off the preceding  " / " in your ajax url parameter. Ex. "ajax/search" vs "/ajax/search"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Jquery script to remove any query parameters from the url

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.history.pushState` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/search",
            data: {query: data},
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function (a) {                        
              console.log(a);
              if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) { # removes the params in URL if exists
                 window.history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname); # this is the magic
                 }
            }
});
```

Comment: how does this differ from my answer?

Comment: But why is the GET parameter added in the first place? It should typically return back to the original URL.

Comment: @NikosVitaTopiko You are using it on document.ready, don't know why one should do that, calling `pushState` after the action makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Nikil Em  If you are using this one a form with method=get, this is expected.! are you using this in a form

Comment: @rrmerugu I'm trying to implement a search functionality in a form with a button(but not type='submit'). And I'm making the ajax call on .click() event after validating the form. The request and response works perfectly as expected. But, after the .ajax() block has completed execution successfully, the URL changes for some reason.

Comment: Can't comment until I see your form html and  JS code of the click event. But it form is submitted with buttom(type=submit) or submitted by jquery, a form(method=get) will append the url with params,

Comment: Did my code, fix your issue -  params being added to the url ?